How to invoke Oracle procedure with TABLE OF RECORD TYPE as input parameter from Java Spring Boot
Good Day Everyone!
I am trying to invoke an Oracle procedure from my Spring Boot microservice with structure similar to below.
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME(INPUT_T IN OUT  RECORD_TABLE_INPUT_T, out_ErrorMsg                        OUT     VARCHAR2 );

The input parameter is a table of record type as given below
TYPE RECORD_TABLE_INPUT_T IS TABLE OF RECORD_TABLE_INPUT_T_COLL INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

RECORD_TABLE_INPUT_T_COLL is defined as below
TYPE FT_BATCH_INPUTS_PARAM_COLL IS RECORD (

variable_one VARCHAR2(10),
variable_two VARCHAR2(10)

);

I am aware that I can use java.sql.Struct for a single Oracle RECORD type but could not find any official documentation or any sample code on how to invoke procedures with this type of input parameter. Please advise.

Doc: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html
read §: "Do Oracle's JDBC drivers support PL/SQL tables/result sets/records/booleans?"
